# Confused about the comma at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar, commas

Examples:

> We haven't spent much time together(,)
>   recently.
>
> I think you're good at
>   dealing with problems. And not only yours—but other’s(,) too.”

I always get confused by this. Should the comma be in those places? Is there any technique to figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of greater context, I'd say "No" to the first, though it's possible that there might be a context where it would be desirable, but I can't think of one at the moment.

With respect to the second, yes, I'd use a comma, there.